# login function doesn't work in firefox but works on chrome,IE,safari and opera

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, firefox

i made a login for my backend web page using jquery.

here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" autocomplete='off'>

    <h1 class="white-text">ADMIN Log in</h1>
    <div class="row"><div id="errMsg"></div></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12"><input type="text" placeholder="User ID" name="txtUsername" id="txtUsername"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12"><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p><a href="#"  data-reveal-id="myModal">Need Help Signing in?</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-12 columns ">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="button right" onclick="validLogin()"> 
    </div>                
</form>
```

here is the jQuery that handles the login:

```
function validLogin(){

      var username=$('#txtUsername').val();
      var password=$('#txtPassword').val();

      var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&password='+ password;

      $("#errMsg").hide();
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "processed.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
               var result=trim(result);
               if(result=='admin'){
                     window.location='admin.php';
               }else if(result=='Invalid ID or password!') {
                     $("#errMsg").show(100);                           
                     $("#errMsg").html("LOGIN FAILED!: " + result);                           
               }else{
                      $("#errMsg").fadeIn(100);                              
                      $("#errMsg").html(result);                            
               }
      }
      });
}
```

and here is the php file from the url of the jquery:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('include/connection.php');

$message=array();
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
}else{
    $message[]='<i class="foundicon-error"></i> username';

}

if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password=stripslashes($_POST['password']);
}else{
    $message[]='<i class="foundicon-error"></i> password';

}

$countError=count($message);

if($countError > 0){
    echo "Please enter your ";
     for($i=0;$i<$countError;$i++){
                if ($i > 0){ 
                    $con=" and "; 
                }else { 
                    $con=""; 
                }
              echo $con.$message[$i];
     }

}else{
    $query="select * from admin_users where username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            $userlvl = $row['user_level'];
        }
    $checkUser=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if($checkUser > 0){
         $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;

         $_SESSION['uname']=$username;
         if ($userlvl == 1) {
            echo 'admin';
         }
         else {
            echo 'techadmin';
         }

    }else{
        echo "Invalid ID or password!";
    }

}
?>
```

i have no clue why do these codes doesn't work on firefox but it works flawlessly on chrome, IE, opera and safari..

it doesn't go to the page where it is intended to go... it just stays on the login page... no error returns or whatsoever... and also, there are no error logs in the console

Comment: And what means `doesn't work` ??? Error in console???

Comment: @A.Wolff it doesn't go to the page where it is intended to go... it just stays on the login page... no error returns or whatsoever... and also, there are no error logs in the console

Comment: It should have one regarding `event`

Comment: you shouldn't use `onclick` on your submit button, try to use `onsubmit` inside your form tag to execute `validLogin`

Comment: @bbuecherl still doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

```
function validLogin(){
   event.preventDefault();
   ^
```

event is not defined, causes javascript abort.

also check a developer console, F12 key, or install a plugin FireBug for Firefox and see what console says.

**EDIT**

Are you sure that jQuery is enabled?
Can you post a jsfiddle for this case with full scenario?

Check console to see javascript errors, maybe you have parsing error somewhere, developer console will help.

**EDIT2**

change form

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validLogin();" action="#" autocomplete='off'>
     .....
    <div class="large-12 columns ">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="button right">
    </div>
</form>
```

and Js to:

```
function validLogin(){

      var username=$('#tx....
      .....
      .....

      return false;  // at the end
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/9kcx9/

Comment: i tried commenting it out and nothing happened

Comment: @ChristianBurgos, check edit. post jsfiddle and debug with developer console.

Comment: yes its all included, the codes work on all browsers except firefox.. there are no errors on the console of firebug

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem. First give `form` an id:

```
<form method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off" id="myform">

    <h1 class="white-text">ADMIN Log in</h1>
    <div class="row"><div id="errMsg"></div></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12"><input type="text" placeholder="User ID" name="txtUsername" id="txtUsername"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12"><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p><a href="#"  data-reveal-id="myModal">Need Help Signing in?</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-12 columns ">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="button right"> 
    </div>                
</form>
```

`validLogin` will have a Event passed, catch it using `evt` as parameter, using `evt.preventDefault( )` and `return false;` (at the end) to prevent the default submit actions. Get your form element and set `onsubmit=validLogin`.

```
function validLogin(evt){
      evt.preventDefault( );
      var username=$('#txtUsername').val();
      var password=$('#txtPassword').val();

      var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&password='+ password;

      $("#errMsg").hide();
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "processed.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
               var result=trim(result);
               if(result=='admin'){
                     window.location='admin.php';
               }else if(result=='Invalid ID or password!') {
                     $("#errMsg").show(100);                           
                     $("#errMsg").html("LOGIN FAILED!: " + result);                           
               }else{
                      $("#errMsg").fadeIn(100);                              
                      $("#errMsg").html(result);                            
               }
      }
      });
      return false;
}
document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = validLogin;
```

tested [here](http://jsbin.com/bipel/1/edit), works in firefox and chrome (open the jsbin console to see its working )

Comment: it still doesn't work. this codes doesn't also work on all of the browser.

Comment: @ChristianBurgos edited my answer and added a jsbin, should work now

Comment: it will not work because you didn't include the php file... my php file returns the result..

Comment: its just for testing purposes, i can not use your php file on jsbin. I tested (and everything works): Cross-browser, prevent default action, generate correct dataString

Comment: ok im gonna test it again.. i really don't understand why it doesn't work onmy end.

Comment: if it still does not work please point out the expected behavior and what firefox does.